# Creating package.scala file in Intellij

Tags: java, scala

Is there a way to let IntelliJ allow me to create a package object file in scala called `package.scala` without telling me that it's an invalid name for a file since it is a java keyword?

Comment: Do you have the Scala plugin installed and your Scala code inside a folder called "scala" (like src/scala/)?

Comment: I do have Scala plugin and working inside `src/scala` but I'm working with a large multi-module maven project something might be configured making my directory not treated as `src/scala` I believe.

Comment: In a non-Play Framework project, your Scala code shouldn't be in `src/scala`, but inside `src/main/scala`. IntelliJ IDEA counts on those kinds of conventions to validate certain things. Maybe it's causing your issue?

Comment: @DavidCastillo Very sorry but that was a typo in my part. I am in `src/main/scala`. thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

You can select these menu items: "New -> Package Object". Version of my IDE is "IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3 (Ultimate Edition)"

[image: menu items]